# Multiple custom calendar controls in webpage is not getting selected using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium web driver and now trying to automate my own project using selenium web driver. My application contains 6 custom calendar controls that i need to select.All the locators are same for this controls.And the only difference is in their xpath's.

```
 calendarcontrol1=//body/div[3]
    calendarcontrol2=//body/div[4]
    calendarcontrol3=//body/div[5]
    calendarcontrol4=//body/div[6]
    calendarcontrol5=//body/div[7]
    calendarcontrol6=//body/div[8]
```

I used classname for identifying the calendar controls.
Below is my code

```
case "SETDATE"      :
        List<WebElement>datewidget=driver.findElements(this.getObject(p,objectName,objectType));
        List<WebElement> calendardate=driver.findElements(By.className("Zebra_DatePicker"));
    int j=2;
        for(int i=0;i<datewidget.size();i++)
            {
            datewidget.get(i).click();
            if(j<calendardate.size())
            {


    calendardate.get(j).findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='dp_current']")).click();
        j=j+1;
            }
            }
```

I am getting the following error while executing the above code.

```
FAILED: testLogin(null, "SETDATE", "setdate", "cssSelector", null)
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not displayed
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
System info: host: 'BCVRTELMS004-V', ip: '172.29.129.228', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '9'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{proxy=Proxy(), acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=11, se:ieOptions={nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:39755/, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false}, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=WINDOWS, setWindowRect=true, platform=WINDOWS}]
Session ID: eb824867-0df3-4b58-97d5-981f0ac0ed89
```

anyone please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Sharing relevant HTML code of elements you are trying to automate will help us understand the problem better.

Comment: <div class="Zebra_DatePicker" style="left: 748.344px; top: 315px; display: block;" xpath="1">
<table class="dp_header" style="width: 218px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="dp_previous">«</td>
<td class="dp_caption">July, 2018</td>
<td class="dp_next">»</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<table class="dp_daypicker">
<tbody>

Comment: Please include the HTML in your question. Also, I cannot really see element with class "dp_current" in the code you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have used correct locators, you can try using JavascriptExecutor to interact with your element.

Why do we use JavascriptExecutor in this case?

There could be another webelement overlaying on top of our target webelement. This means our element is present in the DOM but cannot be interacted with. In such a case, we can click the element using javascript.

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element_xpath"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

Here, ele is the target element.

I would suggest write a method for the Javascript clicking and then call that method for clicking.

For example you could use something like clickButton() and then have the Javascriptexecutor code inside it.